Justification of the change of path of integration of $\Gamma$ in this article
I was reading an article and the author wrote
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{z = -2 \pi i \alpha n \mathbb{R}_+}e^{-z}z^{s-1}dz 
    =   \int_{z = \mathbb{R}_+}e^{-z}z^{s-1}dz
\end{equation*}
where $s= 1/2 + iT$, $\alpha = -1 +i/T$ and $n$ is a positive integer. What's the justification of this change of path ? Only the fact that we're integrating an holomorphic function ?

First simplify $-2\pi i\alpha n\Bbb R_+$. Then, consider the closed path $\left[\frac{i+1/T}{|i+1/T|}R,0\right]\cup[0,R]\cup$ the arc of the circle $|z|=R$ joining the two extremities of these segments, and let $R$ tend to $\infty$.

Did the author really write $z=$? (twice), not $z\in$?

Thanks for your answer !
He wrote it this way (https://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/users/pankaj.vishe/L-value.pdf page 8 equation 3.5)
